# Generating words sounding similar to the ones given in a wordlist -- Core program only

Tags: c++, c++11

This topic is about the same project as [this previous one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/226773/207094).

I think posting the full project was a bit too much, so here I post again only three functions, which are the core of my program, with a few modification from the comments I already had.

The goal is to generate words that sounds similar to a language. In order to do that, we first analyze a dictionary of this language, then generate the words.
The analysis takes the word, as a `Qstring`, and notes each occurrence of each possible letter chain. It depends on a 'coherence length', which means the size of the chain. For example, on the word 'test' with a coherence length of 3 we have to note the occurrence of `"void, void, t"`, `"void, t, e"`, `"t, e, s"`, `"e, s ,t"`, `"s, t, end"`.

This is stored in `charmap`: the key of the map is a vector of `Qchar` (a.k.a, the character chain, e.g. `"t, e, s"`), and the value is a pair where first is the number of occurrence and the second is a probability associated to each key (handled outside of the function).

On this function, I construct the `charmap` word after word:

```
void QanalyzeWord(const QString &word, map<vector<QChar>, pair<int,double>> &charmap, uint lcoh, int &nb) {
    vector<QChar> letterChain(lcoh,'\0');

    for(int i=0; i<word.size(); i++) {
        letterChain[lcoh-1]=word.at(i);
        charmap[letterChain].first++;
        nb++;
        for(uint j=0; j<lcoh-1; j++) {
            letterChain[j]=letterChain[j+1];
        }
    }

    //Indicates last character is void
    letterChain[lcoh-1]='\0';
    charmap[letterChain].first++;
    return;
}
```

Once the full dictionary has been analyzed, we still have to give, to each letter chain, a probability of occurrence. This means completing the `second` of the pair in the `charmap`.

I didn't manage to explain this part clearly, so the best is with the simplest example:

If the `charmap` indicates that `thi` has been encountered 6 times, `the` 3 times and `tho` 1 time, and no other letter is possible after `th`, then we want to gives a probability of 0.6 to `thi`, 0.3 to `the` and 0.1 to `tho`. In addition, we will be doing cumulative probability, so since `the` comes before `thi` then `tho` in the map, we will have `charmap["the"].second=0.3`  `charmap['thi'].second=0.3+0.6` and `charmap['tho'].second=0.3+0.6+0.1` (always sums up to one).

```
std::map<std::vector<QChar>, std::pair<int,double>>::iterator it = charmap.begin() , cePrBegin , cePrEnd;
//cePrBegin and cePrFin are iterators to the beginning and the end of the letter chain currently on the scope

while(it!=charmap.end()) {
    std::vector<QChar> cePr(&it->first[0], &it->first[lcoh-1]);
    cePrBegin = it;
    int nbPosLet = 0; //number of possible letters after 'cePr'

    //We go from cePrBeging to cePrEnd 2 times:
    //1st: counting occurence of each chain

    while( (it!=charmap.end()) && (cePr==std::vector<QChar>(&it->first[0], &it->first[lcoh-1])) ) {
        nbPosLet += it->second.first; //it->second = the pair in the charmap / then .first = the 'int'= nb of occurences
        it++;
    }
    cePrEnd = it;

    //2nd: dividing occurence number / total + add (we are doing cumulative probability)
    for(std::map<std::vector<QChar>, std::pair<int,double>>::iterator secondPass = cePrBegin; secondPass!=cePrEnd && secondPass!=charmap.end(); ++secondPass) {
        secondPass->second.second = double(secondPass->second.first) / nbPosLet;
        if (secondPass != cePrBegin && secondPass!=charmap.begin() )
            secondPass->second.second += prev(secondPass)->second.second; //prev() = previous element
    }
}
```

We may now generate a word. We want to find, letter after letter, which letter we should append to the word. For this, we get a random number r in [0,1]. From the previous example, if r < 0.3 we append a `e` to `th`, if 0.3 < r < 0.9 it's an `i` and if 0.9 < r < 1 it's an `o`.

For this, we have two iterators representing `th\firsPossibleCharacter` and `th\lastPossibileCharacter` and go from one to the other, comparing r to the second of the pair each time.

Note that end of word if a character like any other, but we can force the size of the word, it if ever it gets to long.

```
string Qgenerateur(std::map<std::vector<QChar>, pair<int,double>> &charmap, uint lcoh, uint maxsize) {
    QString myword="";

    vector<QChar> cePr(lcoh-1,'\0'); //represents the chain of previous characters
    vector<QChar> cePrMin, cePrMax; //represents the chain of previous character + the first (resp. last) possible character
    cePrMin.reserve(lcoh); cePrMax.reserve(lcoh);
    map<vector<QChar>, pair<int,double>>::iterator it, itLow, itHigh;
    //itLow : iterator to the first element of the map having this chain of previous character (=cePr)
    //itHigh: iterator to the element after the last element of the map having this chain of previous character (=cePr)

    do {
        cePrMin=cePr;   cePrMin.push_back(QChar::Null);
        cePrMax=cePr;   cePrMax.push_back(QChar::LastValidCodePoint);

        itLow = charmap.lower_bound(cePrMin);
        itHigh = charmap.upper_bound(cePrMax);
        it = itLow;

        double r = double(rand())/ RAND_MAX; // 0 < r < 1
        while (r > it->second.second && it != itHigh) { //places iterator to the 1st caracter having a probability less than r
            it++;
        }
        myword += QString(it->first.back()); //append this caracter to the word
        //it.first is the vector of QChar, representing the letter chain. We append its last letter to our word (the previous letters are already in the word)

        for(uint i=0; i<cePr.size()-1; i++) {
            cePr[i] = cePr[i+1];
        }
        cePr[cePr.size()-1] = it->first.back();
    } while ( (it->first.back()!='\0') && uint(myword.size()) <= maxsize);
    return myword.toStdString();
}
```

Here it is, we have invented a word. It's a bit complicated (for myself at least, I got confused multiple times). I do not especially expect a review from the algorithmic point of view, more for the code itself, for improvement or clarity.

Note the use of Qt `Qstring` and `Qchar`. This is the best solution I found to handle accentuated letter (I'm messed up with `wchar_t`, didn't manage to did it easily), but maybe there is another solution?

I also had one question: I wanted to monitor the progress of the analysis, so I added the `nb` parameter to `QanalyzeWord`. Is there a solution to do this debugging without modifying the function prototype (e.g. don't have `nb` in the prototype), knowing that this is only for debugging, not final release?

And also: should I have used `auto` instead of these awfully long iterator type?

Comment: Are the any changes in this code from the original question?

Comment: I applied the suggested modification (English only, consistent syntax), but the difference is its only 3 (very small) parts and not the whole program

Comment: Do you have a GitHub or GitLab account or some other repository that you could provide a link to. I didn't see one on the other question either. It might be good as hiring employers might like to view your code.

Comment: I'm not really sure I wantpotential employer to see _that_, first I would like to know about its quality... Anyway I would set up one, it will allow to test it

Comment: it's done, full project can be found [here on Github](https://github.com/Sayanel01/GeMot)

Answer (score 1):

I find your code very dense and difficult to skim. I think you can help it quite a bit by making sure each statement is on a line by itself; that there's whitespace around your operators; and that you use `std::` qualification on standard library types and functions. More controversially, I would say "don't abuse `foo++` to mean `foo += 1`" — the shorthand operator should be used only in idioms such as `for`.

Also, I'd avoid cryptic abbreviations like `uint` for `unsigned` — and in fact, I'd avoid `unsigned` types in APIs altogether!

You also write `word.at(i)` where `word[i]` would suffice; and in fact you don't need `i` at all if you just use a plain old ranged for loop `for (QChar ch : word)`.

So where you had

```
void QanalyzeWord(const QString &word, map<vector<QChar>, pair<int,double>> &charmap, uint lcoh, int &nb) {
    vector<QChar> letterChain(lcoh,'\0');

    for(int i=0; i<word.size(); i++) {
        letterChain[lcoh-1]=word.at(i);
        charmap[letterChain].first++;
        nb++;
        for(uint j=0; j<lcoh-1; j++) {
            letterChain[j]=letterChain[j+1];
        }
    }

    //Indicates last character is void
    letterChain[lcoh-1]='\0';
    charmap[letterChain].first++;
    return;
}
```

I would write

```
void QanalyzeWord(
    const QString& word,
    std::map<std::vector<QChar>, std::pair<int, double>>& charmap,
    int lcoh,
    int& nb)
{
    std::vector<QChar> letterChain(lcoh, '\0');

    for (QChar ch : word) {
        charmap[letterChain].first += 1;
        nb += 1;
        letterChain[lcoh - 1] = ch;
        for (int j = 0; j < lcoh - 1; ++j) {
            letterChain[j] = letterChain[j+1];
        }
    }

    letterChain[lcoh-1] = '\0';
    charmap[letterChain].first += 1;
}
```

---

The next thing to look at is that inner loop (`for (int j...)`). It looks wrong at a glance, because it seems to be "shifting down" every letter in the array... but we've already overwritten one of the letters in the array with a new value! It looks like what we meant to write was

```
        for (int j = 0; j < lcoh - 1; ++j) {
            letterChain[j] = letterChain[j+1];
        }
        letterChain[lcoh - 1] = ch;
```

or more concisely,

```
        std::copy(letterChain.begin() + 1, letterChain.end(), letterChain.begin());
        letterChain.back() = ch;
```

or more concisely,

```
        QChar *first = &letterChain[0];
        *first = ch;
        std::rotate(first, first + lcoh, first + 1);
```

---

The line `charmap[letterChain].first += 1;` also wants some attention. What is `.first`? Well, we can look at the function signature and find that `charmap[letterChain]` is a `std::pair<int, double>`. But we don't know what the `int` and the `double` represent. So it would help the reader understand the code if we created a custom data type:

```
struct MapEntry {
    int occurrences = 0;
    double not_sure_what_this_is = 0.0;
};
```

And then we could write

```
charmap[letterChain].occurrences += 1;
```

which is a little bit clearer. I suspect that the names `charmap` and `MapEntry` both could be improved. Naming is important!

---

I didn't really look at the other snippets in your question, but I did notice this part:

```
if (cePr==std::vector<QChar>(&it->first[0], &it->first[lcoh-1])) ...
```

Heap-allocating a vector just to do a comparison seems like overkill. You should look into the [`std::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) algorithm

```
if (std::equal(cePr.begin(), cePr.end(), it->first.begin(), it->first.end() - 1)) ...
```

or just write a helper function that can compare two ranges for you.

```
if (vector_begins_with(it->first, cePr)) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for for review! I learnt some there. What would be a suitable name for `charmap` (it is, after all, a map in which characters are the keys)? Also the double in the pair is a probability (of seeing this key occur), it is handled in the second block of code in the post.

Comment: "What would be a suitable name for `charmap` (it is, after all, a map in which characters are the keys)" — Right, I can see that it's a map of char to double just based on the type. But what does it _represent?_ From your comment it sounds like maybe it's a frequency or probability histogram, such that `charmap[k]` represents the probability of character `k`? In that case, `probability_of_character[k]` would be a pretty self-descriptive name.